# One-line for loop as a function argument

Tags: python, for-loop, syntactic-sugar

```
def strange_syntax(stuff):
    return ".".join(item for item in stuff)
```

How (and why) works this code? What happens here? Normally I can't use this syntax. Also, this syntax doesn't exist if it's not inside some *function* as an argument.

I know, I could do the same with:

```
def normal_syntax(stuff):
    return ".".join(stuff)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used in a function call, the syntax:

```
f(a for a in b)
```

implicitly is compiled as a generator, meaning

```
f((a for a in b))
```

This is just syntactic sugar, to make the program look nicer. It doesn't make much sense to write directly in the console

```
>>>a for a in b
```

because it's unclear if you want to create a generator, or perform a regular loop. In this case you must use the outer `()`.

Comment: Is it possible to do sth like this: `format((key(i) for i in dict_var) = func(i))`? What I want it to be is, with `dict_var` being `{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}` `sql.SQL('query').format(key1=sql.Identifier('value1'), key2=sql.Identifier('value2'))` (`from psycopg2 import sql` was used)

Answer (score 5):

This is called a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator%20expression#generator-expressions).

It works just like a list comprehension (but evaluating the iterated objects lazily and not building a new list from them), but you use parentheses instead of brackets to create them. And you can drop the parentheses in a function call that only has one argument.

In your specific case, there is no need for a generator expression (as you noted) - `(item for item in stuff)` gives the same result as `stuff`. Those expressions start making sense when doing something with the items like `(item.strip() for item in stuff)` (map) or `(item for item in stuff if item.isdigit())` (filter) etc.

Comment: Thanks. I also found thread about generators here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python It's nicely explained there.